# Props value based on a stored cookie

Tags: reactjs

Based on a specific value from a stored cookie (`selectedRetailerId`) the source (API endpoint) is different.

I'm trying to store the value of the cookie in a variable called retailer_id and use that to make sure the correct endpoint is called.

Here's what I'm trying...

```
<OTHER CODE IS REDACTED>

ReactDOM.render(
  function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }

  var retailer_id = getCookie(selectedRetailerId);

  <DeliveryOptionsTable source="http://<REDACTED>/delivery_options/{retailer_id}" />,
  document.getElementById('deliveryOptionsContainer')
)
```

But this returns a Uncaught SyntaxError. Probably because this piece of code should not be in `ReactDOM.render`.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:8000/src/app.js: Unexpected token (130:2)
  128 |   }
  129 | 
> 130 |   var retailer_id = getCookie(selectedRetailerId);
      |   ^
  131 | 
  132 |   <DeliveryOptionsTable source="http://<REDACTED>/delivery_options/{retailer_id}" />,
  133 |   document.getElementById('deliveryOptionsContainer')
```

What is the right way to do this with React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Defined somewhere outside ReactDOM.render (I'd recommend a helpers.js file)
// If you move it out of this file, be sure to import / require it
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DeliveryOptionsTable source={"http://<REDACTED>/delivery_options/" + getCookie(selectedRetailerId)} />,
  document.getElementById('deliveryOptionsContainer')
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It makes a call to `http://<REDACTED>/delivery_options/%7BselectedRetailerId%7D` instead of parsing the `selectedRetailerId` variable.

Comment: You're right, forgot to use curly braces around `source`.  Try now